# How can I create a Material UI Autocomplete component to work with graphql queries?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, graphql, material-ui

I'm using React Typescript and have a Autocomplete Material UI component. I'm trying to get query suggestions into Autocomplete component.

My graphql queries looks like this:

Query Definition:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {useQuery} from 'react-apollo';
import {Autocomplete} from '@material-ui/lab';
const TODOS = gql`
  query todos($id: ID!) {
    todo(id: $id) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Query Initialization:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(TODOS, {
  variables: { id: 1 }
});
```

Autocomplete component

```
{loading ? (
                <p>Loading ...</p>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <div>
                    {data &&
                  data.todo &&
                  data.todo.map(
                    (idx: {id: number; name: string}) => (
                      <Autocomplete
                        id="combo-box-demo"
                        options={idx.name}
                        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
                        style={{width: 300}}
                        renderInput={params => (
                          <TextField
                            {...params}
                            label="Combo box"
                            variant="outlined"
                          />
                        )}
                      />
                    )
                  )}
```

I'm receiving the following errors:

1. For line: "options={idx.name}" - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'unknown[]'.
2. For line: "getOptionLabel={option => option.name}" - Object is of type 'unknown'.

I had the following problems:

- How can I get this working?
- What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options expects an array, you're passing a string.
`Object is of type 'unknown'` is a generic TS error message. I think if you typed it like this:

```
 getOptionLabel={(option: {name: string}) => option.name}
```

it should stop.

Comment: How can I set id to the query and then send the updated query to the autocomplete component?

Comment: You can check follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66418993/pass-graphql-variable-to-the-material-ui-component