# Pass graphql variable to the Material UI component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, material-ui, apollo

I'm using React Typescript and have a Autocomplete Material UI component. I'm trying to get query suggestions into Autocomplete component.

My graphql queries looks like this:

Query Definition:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {useQuery} from 'react-apollo';

const TODOS = gql`
  query todos($id: ID!) {
    todo(id: $id) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Query Initialization:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(TODOS, {
  variables: { id }
});
```

I want to create a autocomplete component which will take a numeric value from the textfield component and pass it on to the autocomplete material ui component?

My numeric component looks like this:

```
 <TextField
          id="filled-number"
          label="Number"
          type="number"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          variant="filled"
        />
```

Autocomplete component:

```
<Autocomplete
                        id="combo-box-demo"
                        options={idx.name}
                        getOptionLabel={(option: {name: string}) => option.name}
                        style={{width: 300}}
                        renderInput={params => (
                          <TextField
                            {...params}
                            label="Combo box"
                            variant="outlined"
                          />
```

So it should set id from the number textfield component and then pass the query to the autocomplete component?

Comment: Do you want to pass the result of your query to the autocomplete component?

Comment: Yes..i want the result in the autocomplete and the textfield component will filter it by providing id to the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where idx.name comes from but it seems it is not an array while `Autocomplete`'s property `options` requires an array type as a value.

You need to pass `data.todo` into the `Autocomplete` prop `options`.

Then you have to make your TextField component be controlled by state.

Code example:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(%INITIAL_VALUE_IF_NEEDED%);
  
  const { data } = useQuery(DATA, {
    variables: { id },
  });

  const handleId = id => setId(id);

  return (
    <Fragment>
     <TextField {...params}
       label="Combo box"
       variant="outlined"
       onChange={handleChange}
     />
     <Autocomplete
       id="combo-box-demo"
       options={data?.todo || []}
       getOptionLabel={(option: {name: string}) => option.name}
       style={{width: 300}}
       renderInput={params => (
         <TextField
           {...params}
           label="Combo box"
           variant="outlined"
         />
       )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

And then every time the id updates in the useQuery you will be able to see the options

Comment: How can I use it if I have 2 queries to run? i.e. 2 textfield and 2 autocomplete components

Comment: If you mean issue with that `data` variable is already declared you can just add an alias to it. I.e. { data: dataA } and { data: dataB }